# Read and Save Data from Inputs to Database on Submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, sql-insert

I have a form with multiple input fields. Using AJAX, I want the inputs to be saved into a database on submit. There are three different tables that the information will need to be inserted into, with each table taking a few of the inputs as you can see in my insert.php code. I have a lot of code and am not sure what I need to add in order to get the information that is entered, saved to the database on submit.

What needs added/changed so that when I click submit, the data will be saved to the related tables in my database?

I did not post my HTML code for the sake of cutting back on the amount of code in my question, but I can post it quickly if needed.

JavaScript:

```
$( function() {

      var emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      phoneRegex = /^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/,
      vendor = $( "#ven" ),
      prog_name = $( "#program_name1" ),
      prog_period = $( "#period" ),
      terms = $( "#year" ),
      type = $( "#type" ),
      name = $( "#name" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      phone = $( "#tel" ),
      tier = $( "#tier" ),
      purchase = $( "#purchase_min" ),
      multiplier = $( "#multiplier" ),
      uom = $( "#uom" ),
      retro = $( "#retro" ),
      guaranteed = $( "#guarenteed" ),
      paid = $( "#paid" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( vendor ).add( prog_name ).add( prog_period ).add( terms ).add( type ).add( name ).add( email ).add( phone ).add( tier ).add( purchase ).add( multiplier ).add( uom ).add( retro ).add( guaranteed ).add( paid );
  console.log(allFields);

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

   function submitInfo() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// ----- Validation for each input in add row dialog box -----
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( vendor, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid vendor name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( prog_name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid program name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( terms, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter valid terms" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/, "Please enter a valid name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( email, emailRegex, "Please enter a valid email" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( phone, phoneRegex, "Please enter a valid phone number" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( purchase, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid purchase minimum" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( multiplier, /^\d*\.?\d*$/, "Please enter a valid multiplier" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( uom, /[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/, "Please enter a valid uom" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( retro, /^[0]{1}$/, "Please enter a valid entry for retro" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( guaranteed, /^[0-1]{1}$/, "Please enter a valid entry for guaranteed" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( paid, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid entry for paid" );
      console.log(allFields);
      if ( valid ) {
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          var type = $(this).attr('id');
          var value = $(this).val();
          console.log(type + " : " + value);
          // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
          switch (type) {
            case "ven":
                dict["MR_Name"] = value;
              break;
            case "program_name1":
                dict["Program_Name"] = value;
              break;
            case "period":
                dict["Program_Year"] = value;
              break;
            case "year":
                dict["Terms"] = value;
                break;
            case "type":
                dict["Coded"] = value;
                break;
            case "name":
                dict["MR_POC_N"] = value;
                break;
            case "email":
                dict["MR_POC_E"] = value;
                break;
            case "tel":
                dict["MR_POC_P"] = value;
                break;
            case "tier":
                dict["Tier"] = value;
              break;
            case "purchase_min":
                dict["Tier Minimum"] = value;
              break;
            case "mulitplier":
                dict["Multiplier"] = value;
                break;
            case "uom":
                dict["UOM"] = value;
                break;
            case "retro":
                dict["Retro"] = value;
                break;
            case "guaranteed":
                dict["Guaranteed"] = value;
                break;
            case "paid":
                dict["Pay"] = value;
                break;
            }
        });
        console.log(dict);

    var selIndex = ven.selectedIndex;
    console.log();
    var selName = $("#ven").val();

        var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert.php",
          data: { ven: selName, MR_Name: dict['MR_Name'], Program_Name: dict['Program_Name'], Program_Year: dict['Program_Year'], Terms: dict['Terms'], Coded: dict['Coded'], MR_POC_N: dict['MR_POC_N'],  MR_POC_E: dict['MR_POC_E'],  MR_POC_P: dict['MR_POC_P'], Tier: dict['Tier'], 'Tier Minimum': dict['Tier Minimum'], Multiplier: dict['Multiplier'], UOM: dict['UOM'], Retro: dict['Retro'], Guaranteed: dict['Guaranteed'], Pay: dict['Pay'] }
        });

// Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });

      }
      return valid;
    }
});
```

Insert.php:

```
<?php

  $MR_Name = $_POST['MR_Name'];
  $Program_Name = $_POST['Program_Name'];
  $Program_Year = $_POST['Program_Year'];
  $Terms = $_POST['Terms'];
  $Coded = $_POST['Coded'];
  $MR_POC_N = $_POST['MR_POC_N'];
  $MR_POC_E = $_POST['MR_POC_E'];
  $MR_POC_P = $_POST['MR_POC_P'];
  $Tier = $_POST['Tier'];
  $Tier_Minimum = $_POST['Tier Minimum'];
  $Multiplier = $_POST['Multiplier'];
  $UOM = $_POST['UOM'];
  $Retro = $_POST['Retro'];
  $Guaranteed = $_POST['Guaranteed'];
  $Pay = $_POST['Pay'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Master (MR_Name, MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Programs (Program_Name, Program_Year) VALUES (?, ?)";
  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Agreements (Terms, Tier, Tier Minimum, Multiplier, UOM, Retro, Guaranteed, Pay) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
  $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
  $result = $stmt->execute(array($MR_Name, $MR_POC_N, $MR_POC_E, $MR_POC_P));
  $result1 = $stmt1->execute(array($Program_Name, $Program_Year));
  $result2 = $stmt2->execute(array($Terms, $Tier, $Tier_Minimum, $Multiplier, $UOM, $Retro, $Guaranteed, $Pay));
  echo json_encode($result);
  echo json_encode($result1);
  echo json_encode($result2);

?>
```

Comment: you don't want  `var request = ...` just call the `$.ajax(...)`

Comment: I actually have below that in my JS...a `request.done` and `request.fail` function so i think i would use it

Comment: at what point do you see an issue/error ?  And you cannot have `request` inside this `submitInfo` and call it elsewhere outside.

Comment: the request is inside the submitInfo and is called inside submitInfo also...i just dont have it posted to simplify code since thats not the source of the problem....when it comes to an issue/error, i actually dont see any errors at all...but after submit, nothing happens and the data isnt sent to the DB

Comment: i added the request to make it clearer